# Use a MongoHQ db with Meteor on localhost

Tags: meteor, mongohq

I wanted to know how to go about getting a MongoHQ db to work on my localhost installation of Meter.

i tried using the settings.json method or the      `MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@xxxx.mongohq.com:10061/xxxx` when firing up meteor but both dont work and are probably the wrong way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run it like this in your terminal within your project directory

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@xxxx.mongohq.com:10061/xxxx meteor
```

or

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:pass@xxxx.mongohq.com:10061/xxxx
meteor
```

Comment: that did get it to use mongohq however its not make any collections.

Comment: Meteor.startup(function () {
 
 var Customers   = new Meteor.Collection("customers");
 var Contacts    = new Meteor.Collection("contacts");
 
 console.log("Were Here");
 if (Customers.find() === 0) {
  console.log("nothing found for customers");
  Customers.insert({id: Customers.find().count() + 1, name: "Test Customer"});
 };
 console.log("Were now here");
 if (Contacts.find({}) === 0) {
  console.log("nothing found for customers");
  Contacts.insert({id: Contacts.find().count() + 1, first_name: "Test", last_name: "Contact"});
 };
 
});

Comment: Was that server side or client side code? You have to wait for the subscriptions to complete before you can check whether the collections are filled up. Does it work on the normal local mongodb database btw?

Comment: I believe it was working correctly, However I cant seem to be able to change the MONGO_URL back to meteor default so I can test it with meteor mongo from the console to be sure.

Comment: did you use the export method? Use a new terminal

Comment: There are also a couple of mistakes with your code `Customers.find()` will never `===0` & `var Customers` isn't global. With the corrections it would work as expected provided you wait for subscriptions on the client

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26881/discussion-between-moshe-and-akshat)